# What is the meaning of all of the k9s headings? - some are obvious, and some less-so

Tags: kubernetes

In particular, %CPU/R, %CPU/L, %MEM/R, and %MEM/L. While I'm at it, what are the units of the memory and CPU (non-percentage) columns?

Comment: Where are you looking those metrics? kubectl? K8s Dashboard? GKE? Anyway I'm guessing this is CPU/(R)equested and CPU/(L)imit. The absolute number most likely is the vCPU equivalent/miliCPU which you can know more about here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/#specify-a-cpu-request-and-a-cpu-limit

Comment: I believe this question is about data displayed by the [k9s](https://k9scli.io/) command.

Comment: @larsks oh that makes sense.

Answer (score 39):

They are explained in the K9s release notes [here](https://github.com/derailed/k9s/blob/master/change_logs/release_v0.13.4.md#cpumem-metrics)

- %CPU/R    Percentage of requested cpu
- %MEM/R    Percentage of requested memory
- %CPU/L    Percentage of limited cpu
- %MEM/L    Percentage of limited memory

Comment: That's a perfect answer for the headings. The clarification and link from @Nathan above fills in the rest. I was pretty sure L and R weren't left and right ;-)

Comment: Just to add, these columns were added in this PR - https://github.com/derailed/k9s/pull/489

Answer (score 10):

In https://gist.github.com/BigNerd/35a56e411df4c90f7d6dee1d33dbd0a5 here, the author explained more. And I copy his content here:

```
View: Pods(<namespace>)[number of pods listed]

NAME      pod name
READY     number of pods in ready state / number of pods to be in ready state
RESTARTS  number of times the pod has been restarted so far
STATUS    state of the pod life cycle, such as Running | ... | Completed
CPU       current CPU usage, unit is milli-vCPU
MEM       current main memory usage, unit is MiB
%CPU/R    current CPU usage as a percentage of what has been requested by the pod
%MEM/R    current main memory usage as a percentage of what has been requested by the pod
%CPU/L    current CPU usage as a percentage of the pod's limit (it cannot go beyond its limit)
%MEM/L    current main memory usage as a percentage of the pod's limit (it cannot go beyond its limit)
IP        IP address of the pod
NODE      name of the node the pod is running on
AGE       age of the pod, units are indicated (s = seconds, m = minutes, h = hours, d = days)
```

His gist should own a star.

Comment: what is "main memory usage", is it container_memory_working_set_bytes, container_memory_rss, total_rss or any of the other ways of counting memory.  it does not correspond to RSS in top.